# Database Design - 'Lists' storage

Tags: database-design

I'm "about" to implement a feature on one of my apps which requires storing a lot of data (PlayLists).

Assume the following scenario:

- A user can have multiple playlists
- These playlists have up to 500k entries (maybe even more)
- I must be able to get, remove, re-sort or query the whole playlist or by using indexes
- Currently a playlist for each user; but
- I'm about to implement a feature that will allow users to have more than 1 playlist.
- About 3500 entries per playlist. Some can go as high as 590k.

Playlist entries are represented by the following class:

```cs
public class Item {
  private Long owner; // User
  private String data;
  private String name;
  private String author;
  private int index; // Index of this item on the list
}
```

**TL;DR**: `List< Item >` for every user (more than 1 per user) where this list can extend to 500k+ entries.

Currently, I have SQL-based storage for this, however, it's slow as heck, specially when I need to shift indexes - slow up to the point of my db driver thinking that the connection failed and leaked.

To explain "shift indexes": Let's say I'm removing an item at the 3rd index (`i = 3`), this means that all other items after it need to shift one index down, so I can later on request index 3 and get the item that was previously index 4.

Currently, I decrement the column value `Order` for that playlist for all elements after the one I deleted.

#### Current PlayList Items Table design

```
Id (Ordering/Index) | PlayList (Id) | Owner (User) | Name | Author | Data
```

#### Question

Which would be a better/more efficient way of storing this kind of "bulk" data, while still being able to query and modify it?

I'm ok with changing/implementing a new database software for this kind of data, since it's really big (I currently use Redis and MariaDB). However, I would love to avoid having to.

Comment: @Fabricio20 (A) How many users, how many rows playlist items in total ( users * 590K max each) ? (B) Are 'data', 'name', 'author', shared across the users – Can we move that info into a parent table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... 1 person can have 590k tracks? Difficult to imagine, however, I have come up with a schema which might make a good starting point. You may want to have a playlist table for each user depending on how many users you have.

I have used PostgreSQL - you should be able to readily translate to another RDBMS - but, if you are going the Open Source route, I would recommend PostgreSQL.

I have also provided a minimal amount of DML (`INSERT` statements) which should let you see where I'm coming from.

The playlist table is an example of an [Associative Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) - otherwise known as a joining table or a many-to-many table - they are very useful.

Obviously, I don't have a real dataset, but I believe that the SQL updating a user's order by 1

```
UPDATE playlist SET pl_order = pl_order + 1 
WHERE pl_user = 123 
AND pl_order > order_to_be_deleted
```

should not be too onerous. Get back to us if you're still having problems. Note, that it should be within a single transaction!

Note also that you can put a lot of your application logic into the database creation script itself - various rules can be enforced without having to write a word of application code!

```
CREATE TABLE my_user  -- "user" is a keyword in PostgreSQL
(
  user_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  user_name VARCHAR(25)
  -- other fields?
  --
);

CREATE TABLE song
(
  song_id SERIAL, CONSTRAINT song_pk PRIMARY KEY (song_id),
  song_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  song_artist VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  song_writer VARCHAR(50), -- may be unknown, i.e. NULL
  song_label VARCHAR(50) 
);


CREATE TABLE playlist
(
  pl_user_id INTEGER, -- NOT NULL not required, see CONSTRAINTs.
  pl_song_id INTEGER, 
  pl_order   INTEGER,

  CONSTRAINT playlist_pk PRIMARY KEY (pl_user_id, pl_song_id),
  CONSTRAINT playlist_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (pl_user_id) REFERENCES my_user (user_id), 
  CONSTRAINT playlist_song_fk FOREIGN KEY (pl_song_id) REFERENCES song (song_id),

  CONSTRAINT pl_user_song_uq UNIQUE (pl_user, pl_song) 
  -- can't have same user and song combo!

  CONSTRAINT pl_user_order_uq UNIQUE (pl_user, pl_order) 
  -- can't have ties of preference

);

CREATE INDEX pl_user_ix ON playlist (pl_user_id);
CREATE INDEX pl_song_ix ON playlist (pl_song_id);

CREATE INDEX pl_user_song_ix on playlist (pl_user_id, pl_song_id); 
-- this is an index which may help with the UDATE query above.


INSERT INTO user (user_name) VALUES ('Fred'), ('Bill'), ('Mary');

INSERT INTO song VALUES ('U2',          'Streets have no name',  NULL, NULL); 
INSERT INTO song VALUES ('Thin Lizzy',  'Boys are back in town', NULL, NULL); 
INSERT INTO song VALUES ('Cranberries', 'Something else',        NULL, NULL); 


INSERT INTO playlist VALUES 
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 3, 3),
(2, 2, 1),
(2, 3, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 3, 1),
(3, 2, 2),
(3, 1, 3);
```

Comment: I'm taking this as the accepted answer since it improves the data that is being stored on the table (avoids duplicates). However, I still don't see a way to improve (the speed of) iterating over the bulk data. Shifting an index here is as slow as in my current/example when you need to shift more than (let's say) 2k entries down to get the pl_order column to be correct. (Unless I'm not understanding the pl_user_order_uq constraint correctly).

Comment: I added an index "CREATE INDEX pl_user_song_ix on playlist (pl_user_id, pl_song_id); -- this is an index which may help with the UDATE query below." which may help with your problem query - have you been able to test on realistic datasets? You may also want to include a genre table or you could do as @BasilBourque suggested - have multiple playlists per user.

Comment: @Fabricio20 Regarding the shifting performance, see edit to my Answer: Increment your sort-order numbers by a hundred, a thousand, or a million, rather than by one. This opens up gaps to be filled in later with new sort-assignments.

Answer (score 5):

## User has >1 playlist

The [Answer by Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185553/19079) is correct except that it skipped the fact that each user may have more than one playlist.

So here is a diagram of my table design. I changed one column name to "sort_order" as the name “index” in a database and in programming will cause all kinds of confusion.

Basically I suspect you are failing to notice the 'list' in 'playlist', conflating each person's list of their favoritesfrom the full list of possible choices. Each playlist is a collection of *references* to the desired items (songs, books, or whatever your matter is  — not clear in the Question).

[image]

## Performance

As for your performance issue when inserting a new/changed row amongst the existing rows’ sort-order  numbers, you can dramatically reduce the frequency of this chore.

**Increment your sort-order value by a hundred or by a thousand or by a million rather than by one.** You can insert a new row by assigning a sort-order number in between the numbers of existing rows without any shifting. You only need to do a full shift when 99 or 999 or 999,999 rows happen to have already been inserted between the incremented rows. Until then you may need to do mini-shifts when clumps appear with the in-between numbers, but on small subset of rows, <100 or <1,000 or <1,000,000.

If you need to show sequential 1, 2, 3… numbers to user, let the database create these numbers dynamically as part of your `SELECT` statement.